# odd delay in strace log when apache serving static content

Tags: linux, apache, sockets, httpd.conf, strace

Using Firefox's developer tools I noticed that static image loads from my site spent between 60-200ms in the "Connect" phase.  I took an strace log and see where the delay happens, but am having trouble understanding why it's happening.  Here is what I see in strace (log slightly edited to remove actual file paths):

```
30727 22:20:52.526972 getsockname(12, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(80), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::ffff:192.168.100.62", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, [28]) = 0
30727 22:20:52.527203 fcntl(12, F_GETFL) = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
30727 22:20:52.527275 fcntl(12, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
30727 22:20:52.527419 read(12, "GET /images/blah/bla"..., 8000) = 540
30727 22:20:52.527737 brk(0x7f72665b7000) = 0x7f72665b7000
30727 22:20:52.527972 stat("/websites/imagesrepository/blah/blah/image.png", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0775, st_size=$
30727 22:20:52.528160 open("/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
30727 22:20:52.528254 open("/websites/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
30727 22:20:52.528335 open("/websites/imagesrepository/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
30727 22:20:52.528417 open("/websites/imagesrepository/blah/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
30727 22:20:52.528501 open("/websites/imagesrepository/blah/blah/.htaccess", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
30727 22:20:52.529090 stat("/websites/somefile.ext", 0x7f7266582d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
30727 22:20:52.529144 stat("/websites/someotherfile.ext", 0x7f72665812d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
30727 22:20:52.529431 open("/websites/imagesrepository/blah/blah/image.png", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 13
30727 22:20:52.529489 fcntl(13, F_GETFD) = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
30727 22:20:52.529519 fcntl(13, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
30727 22:20:52.529582 close(13)         = 0
30727 22:20:52.529669 writev(12, [{"HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified\r\nDate:"..., 209}], 1) = 209
30727 22:20:52.529773 write(10, "104.189.168.66 - - [04/Mar/2015:"..., 270) = 270
30727 22:20:52.529842 shutdown(12, 1 /* send */) = 0
30727 22:20:52.529905 poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN}], 1, 2000) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
30727 22:20:52.687759 read(12, "", 512) = 0
30727 22:20:52.687849 close(12)         = 0
30727 22:20:52.687951 read(8, 0x7fffc3eb081f, 1) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
30727 22:20:52.688062 semop(3145795, {{0, -1, SEM_UNDO}}, 1 <unfinished ...>
```

It looks like the delay occurs here:

```
30727 22:20:52.529905 poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN}], 1, 2000) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLIN|POLLHUP}])
30727 22:20:52.687759 read(12, "", 512) = 0
```

File descriptor 12 is the socket the request came in on.  So it looks like before closing the socket Apache polls for some event and then tries a read?  Why?  I have KeepAlive off in my config file (due to incompatibility with certain older mobile clients) if that matters.

EDITED TO ADD:

I dug into the Apache 2.2 source and this behavior seems to be intentional.  The relevant method is ap_lingering_close() in server/connection.c:

```
/* we now proceed to read from the client until we get EOF, or until
 * MAX_SECS_TO_LINGER has passed.  the reasons for doing this are
 * documented in a draft:
 *
 * http://www.ics.uci.edu/pub/ietf/http/draft-ietf-http-connection-00.txt
 *
 * in a nutshell -- if we don't make this effort we risk causing
 * TCP RST packets to be sent which can tear down a connection before
 * all the response data has been sent to the client.
 */
#define SECONDS_TO_LINGER  2
AP_DECLARE(void) ap_lingering_close(conn_rec *c)
{
    char dummybuf[512];
    apr_size_t nbytes;
    apr_time_t timeup = 0;
    apr_socket_t *csd = ap_get_module_config(c->conn_config, &core_module);

    if (!csd) {
        return;
    }

    ap_update_child_status(c->sbh, SERVER_CLOSING, NULL);

#ifdef NO_LINGCLOSE
    ap_flush_conn(c); /* just close it */
    apr_socket_close(csd);
    return;
#endif

    /* Close the connection, being careful to send out whatever is still
     * in our buffers.  If possible, try to avoid a hard close until the
     * client has ACKed our FIN and/or has stopped sending us data.
     */

    /* Send any leftover data to the client, but never try to again */
    ap_flush_conn(c);

    if (c->aborted) {
        apr_socket_close(csd);
        return;
    }

    /* Shut down the socket for write, which will send a FIN
     * to the peer.
     */
    if (apr_socket_shutdown(csd, APR_SHUTDOWN_WRITE) != APR_SUCCESS
        || c->aborted) {
        apr_socket_close(csd);
        return;
    }

    /* Read available data from the client whilst it continues sending
     * it, for a maximum time of MAX_SECS_TO_LINGER.  If the client
     * does not send any data within 2 seconds (a value pulled from
     * Apache 1.3 which seems to work well), give up.
     */
    apr_socket_timeout_set(csd, apr_time_from_sec(SECONDS_TO_LINGER));
    apr_socket_opt_set(csd, APR_INCOMPLETE_READ, 1);

    /* The common path here is that the initial apr_socket_recv() call
     * will return 0 bytes read; so that case must avoid the expensive
     * apr_time_now() call and time arithmetic. */

    do {
        nbytes = sizeof(dummybuf);
        if (apr_socket_recv(csd, dummybuf, &nbytes) || nbytes == 0)
            break;

        if (timeup == 0) {
            /*
             * First time through;
             * calculate now + 30 seconds (MAX_SECS_TO_LINGER).
             *
             * If some module requested a shortened waiting period, only wait
             * for 2s (SECONDS_TO_LINGER). This is useful for mitigating
             * certain DoS attacks.
             */
            if (apr_table_get(c->notes, "short-lingering-close")) {
                timeup = apr_time_now() + apr_time_from_sec(SECONDS_TO_LINGER);
            }
            else {
                timeup = apr_time_now() + apr_time_from_sec(MAX_SECS_TO_LINGER);
            }
            continue;
        }
    } while (apr_time_now() < timeup);

    apr_socket_close(csd);
    return;
}
```

Still: is it normal for this approach to add 50-150ms to *every* request?  That seems excessive.

EDITED AGAIN TO ADD:

Based on this ancient discussion among Apache devs:

http://webmail.dev411.com/t/apache/dev/9727khxsk3/apache-1-2b7-dev-performance/oldest

and specifically this comment from Roy T. Fielding:

http://webmail.dev411.com/t/apache/dev/9727khxsk3/apache-1-2b7-dev-performance/oldest#19970209aph7g21hj2jepa04nk28ywj6cr

it sounds like this may be a bug.  If KeepAlive is *Off* then it sounds like there's no need to do a lingering close because the client has already been told the connection won't be persistent.

Comment: There could be a zillion reasons. One way to troubleshoot this is to build Apache with debugging info and step through the request execution with a debugger.

Comment: So I turned KeepAlive on and the delay goes away.  Because the connections aren't being closed after each request.  This may just be how this version of Apache closes connections.  Perhaps unnecessarily given KeepAlive is disabled.  Seems like it should just call close() and be done with it.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think this poll thing is a red herring.  The delay I'm seeing happens *before* the resource is streamed over the socket.  So closing should have nothing to do with it.  I think what I'm seeing is just the "normal" behavior when KeepAlive is disabled.  The reason I didn't see similar delays when loading static content from other servers is that they have it *on*.